# How does one extract NDVI data from a band?

Tags: time-series, google-earth-engine

I am trying to look at the change in NDVI over time for a polygon, and I want to have access to the NDVI values themselves, rather than chart or map them. So far, all I seem to be able to do is select a single pixel, chart the NDVI and then export the data as a CSV. This method would be extremely impractical if I wanted to do this for a polygon instead of a pixel.

```js
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: withNDVI.select('ndvi'),
  region: Point,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  scale: 30
}).setOptions({title: 'NDVI over time'});

print(chart);
```

I'm using the above code to plot NDVI over time.

Answer (score 1):

"Have access to" is not really specific enough.  You can check the `getRegion()` method on an image collection.  You may also want to check the `toCollection()` reducer in order to turn the pixels into a `FeatureCollection`.  For more complicated exports of time series in regions, [this reference](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials#tables-and-vectors) may help.